# C++ Element in array first is read correctly, then gives a NaN without having been changed how is that possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, ubuntu, nan, eigen

i'm experiencing the weirdest problem in my programming life. I'm performing an image analysis con a 3D volume of approx 800x800x600 elements, extracting from each pixel an hessian matrix built on the gray scale, and computing some algebra (using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)) after to detect the alignement of the fibres described in the volume.

To build the volume, i use a double[x][y][z] array that i build reading from a nhdr+raw file. So far so good for an intro of the domain problem.

I perform the analysis dividing the big volume in subvolumes (the overall execution time is around 14 hours, but that was expected, as usual for scientific analysis software).
At a certain point, when i am at the x=(max-2) (i stop my analysis 2 pixels before the border) index of the array, for a couple of elements ([792][247][76] and [792][84][56], but there might be others after those ones, still with the x=max probably), my eigen function fails suddenly.

Debuggin i found out that to build the partial derivatives for the Hessian matrix, i access the element [x+2][y][z] and i obtain NaN out it, therefore obviously Eigen goes mad while doing his operations on that.

The weirdest thing is, that if in the beginning of the software (after loading the volume), if i print the value of that exact element, it exists and it has a meaningful value too. How's that possible?? I run the software several times, and for the same two pixels, same error on the same position, so even guessing it might be a RAM error, shouldn't it somehow fluctuate and change position due to other stuff going on in my PC?

I went further with the testing. 
I am looping on the subvolumes, and there everything is fine (i keep on tracking the value of a fixed volume[][][] element, the one on which the failure was manifesting itself)
The pixel value remains unchanged outside the following function, that pixel by pixel is analysing the subvolume. As i know that the value of the pixel i am interested in is 51941 (and it is before getting into the following function for the given subvolum) i put a guard on when the values changes.

Here what happens >
Pixel value in subvolume start:51941
Element :5982; 636,260,62;
Pixel value in loop: 1.65031e-22

After 5982 loops (of more or less 3millions necessary for the full subvolume), the value changes, and nowehere in the following code i touch it! what might cause something like that?

```
Matrix3d HesseAnalysis(int subX, int subY, int subZ, int maxX, int maxY, int maxZ){

//int maxX = subX+deltaX;
//int maxY = subY+deltaY;
//int maxZ = subZ+deltaZ;

int counter=0;

for (int x=subX;x<(maxX-2);x++){
    for (int y=subY;y<(maxY-2);y++){
        for (int z=subZ;z<(maxZ-2);z++){


            if(volume[792][247][76]!=51941){
                cout << "Element :" << counter << "; " << x << "," << y << "," << z << ";" << endl;
                cout << "Pixel value in loop: " << volume[792][247][76]<< endl;
                exit(0);
            }

            fxx=((volume[x+2][y][z]-volume[x][y][z])/2-(volume[x][y][z]-volume[x-2][y][z])/2)/2;
            fyy=((volume[x][y+2][z]-volume[x][y][z])/2-(volume[x][y][z]-volume[x][y-2][z])/2)/2;
            fzz=((volume[x][y][z+2]-volume[x][y][z])/2-(volume[x][y][z]-volume[x][y][z-2])/2)/2;
            fxy=((volume[x+1][y+1][z]-volume[x+1][y-1][z])-(volume[x-1][y+1][z]-volume[x-1][y-1][z]));
            fxz=((volume[x+1][y][z+1]-volume[x+1][y][z-1])-(volume[x-1][y][z+1]-volume[x-1][y][z-1]));
            fyz=((volume[x][y+1][z+1]-volume[x][y+1][z-1])-(volume[x][y-1][z+1]-volume[x][y-1][z-1]));

            //compose hessian matrix for the pixel, remember that  
 hessian <<     fxx, fxy, fxz,
    fxy, fyy, fyz,
    fxz, fyz, fzz;

//extract eigenvalues and choose the eigenvector related to the smallest eigenvalue,
//and do the outer product of it with itself

EigenSolver<Matrix3d> solver(hessian);
int minorEigen = minorEigenvalue(solver.eigenvalues().real());
Vector3d v3 =solver.eigenvectors().col(minorEigen).real();
V3outerV3 = v3*v3.transpose();
OuterProducts[(x-subX)-2][(y-subY)-2][(z-subZ)-2]= V3outerV3;

counter++;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: hard to tell with you showing only the slightest reference to code ... but any chance you're exceeding the array boundary somewhere? you might want to check all instances where you acccess the array via index and set it? It's gotta change somewhere ;) or you have an overflow in another indexed access... you can almost certainly exclude hardware problems. they would have shown up in other programs as well

Comment: Out of curiousity - did you try putting a break point that would break when the value [x+2][y][z] changes?

Comment: hi nyarlathotep, i'm sure i'm not exceeding the array, i'm printing the indexes and they seem to be correct. I think posting the code would be somehow useless, it's some thousands lines of code, and that array is accessed in writing only in the building phase, after which i only read from it. @typical, that might be an idea, i'm dumb i didn't think on it, even if nowhere i change willingly the value of that array.

Comment: @nyarklathotep i added some code and testing, but still i can't get a sense out of the results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. I still didn't have time to explore the real reason, but it depends on a probable bug of Eigen.

this line is the one that causes the mess :

Vector3d v3 =solver.eigenvectors().col(minorEigen).real();

For some reason, at a certain point, it decides to invade the memory already allocated for my volume[ ][ ][ ] array and, and this is the weirdest part, the pixel that i was using for testing, the volume[792][247][76] value, is changed depending on which value the variable minorEigen (that is simply returning the index of the smallest eigenvalue in the function).

So for example with minorEigen = 0 the pixel becomes 1.65031e-22, with minorEigen = 1 it becomes 2.1402e+5... I guess some wird bogus pointer or some similar bug. I will investigate the Eigen bug reports, check for an newer releas, or otherwise implement my own eigensolver for the matrix.

Comment: Problem permanently fixed. It was due to accessing one of eigen vectors with a negative index, and therefore it was writing in the already allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

Generally C/C++ uses 0-based index. If you don't want your `x` to be out of range, should you stop at `x=max-3`, so the index can stay in the range from `0` to `max-1`?

Comment: Hi Eric, i probably didn't explain it correctly, but i stop in the right range, (the array has 795 elements on the "x axis" and i stop at 792, while reading for the computation also 794). i see that i read that index, and as i say, it's a meaningful value when the code starts, but along the computation it reads Nan out of it

Comment: Since your result is repeatable, you must have changed it with some operations, eg. Some of the operations you think is out-place is in fact an in-place operation.

Comment: Yes, even if going through the code didn't show any assignment of a new value to the volume[][][] matrix, definitely somewhere something should have been happening. Yesterday night i left it running on a bigger machine and with some watchpoint, i'll see if something changed when and how.